# Command Prompt window appears with gui window c++

Tags: c++, windows

Whenever I try to make a c++ gui program/window the command prompt window appears with the window like this:

[image]

but all I did was this::

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include "define.h"

    LRESULT CALLBACK WinProc(HWND hWnd,UINT message,WPARAM wParam,LPARAM lParam);

    int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInst, HINSTANCE hPrevInst, LPSTR lpCmdLine, int nShowCmd){

    window win;
    MSG msg;

    win.cbClsExtra = NULL;                             //Additional parameters
    win.cbWndExtra = NULL;                            //Additional parameters
    win.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH)COLOR_WINDOW ;                        //Sets background color for the window
    win.hCursor = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW);      //The cursor that will appear in the window
    win.hIcon = NULL;                              //Icon for the window
    win.hInstance = hInst;                        //Handle to the application instance
    win.lpszClassName = "Window Class";          //The unique name of the window class
    win.lpszMenuName = NULL;                    //Used for menus
    win.style = NULL;                          //The look and feel of the window
    win.lpfnWndProc=(WNDPROC)WinProc;         //The callback procedure (more on that later)

    RegisterClass(&win);
    HWND hwnd = CreateWindow("Window Class", "Title", WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW, 200, 200, 640, 480, NULL, NULL, hInst, NULL);
    ShowWindow(hwnd, SW_SHOWNORMAL);

    while(GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0)){

        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessage(&msg);

    }

    return 0;

    }

    LRESULT CALLBACK WinProc(HWND hWnd,UINT message,WPARAM wParam,LPARAM lParam){

    switch (message){

    case WM_CREATE:{

        HWND button = CreateWindow("BUTTON", "ok", WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD | WS_BORDER, 20, 20, 50, 30, hWnd, NULL, NULL, &lParam);
        break;

    }

    case WM_DESTROY:{

        PostQuitMessage(0);
        return 0;
        break;

    }

    default:{

        return DefWindowProc(hWnd, message, wParam, lParam);

    }
    }


    }
```

I followed the code just on internet and don't think I did something wrong I want to remove this annoying cmd window by any way...

tysm for all repliers much appreciated...........

---

***EDIT***

and btw the define.h is a header file I made and define WNDCLASS as window

Comment: If you're using GCC, try to compile with `-mwindows` flag.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat how to do this??

Comment: I see you're using Code::Blocks. First, did you create a Console application project or a Win32 GUI project? Second, to follow HolyBlackCat's instructions, right-click your project -> "Build Options" -> click your project's name in the options screen that comes up (you want to set this option for all builds; selecting Release or Debug would just set this flag for that mode) -> "Compiler Options" -> "Other options", then type `-mwindows` on a new line in that textbox. Hit "OK" and try rebuilding.

Comment: I'am almost sure it will not work. Code::Blocks will use this flag only when compiling .o files, not .exe. If the console still appears, change `Project > Properties > Build Targets > Type` from `Console Application` to `GUI Application`.